# How to force the MATLAB output in the simple terms?

Tags: matlab, output, symbolic-math

From the textbook, I got the answer `yp_tb = exp(x)*(tan(x)-x)/2;`

From Matlab, I got the answer:

```
yp_mt = (x*exp(x)*tan(x)^2)/2 - (exp(x)*(2*x - sin(2*x)))/(4*cos(x)^2);
```

I made the following script to check whether they are same or not.

```
clear all;
syms x
yp_tb = exp(x)*(tan(x)-x)/2; 
yp_mt = (x*exp(x)*tan(x)^2)/2 - (exp(x)*(2*x - sin(2*x)))/(4*cos(x)^2);
%  yp_tb = textbook output; yp_mt = matlab output 
Equal = isAlways(yp_tb == yp_mt) % Equal is 1, it means they are equal
```

How to force the MATLAB output to be textbook output?

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to say that if the matlab output is incorrect, go with the textbook one?

Comment: Sardar, I get Equal = 1. Marcman, both matlab and textbook are correct. My question: how to force the matlab answer to be the same format as textbook answer

Comment: Have you tried [simplify](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html)?

Comment: Vahe, I have tried it. It was not successful. Thanks.

Comment: use `simplify(yp_mt, 3)` . It leads to the same answer as the textbook. Look at help for the simplify function to understand the command

Comment: Thanks a lot ammportal. It works.

Comment: @ammportal Consider creating an answer or the OP may do it himself.

Comment: @ammportal, how to create it. Normally, I just checked (and the color will be green) as a sign that the problem has been answered.

Comment: @User1961 I have added the answer. please consider accepting it. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding answer since it worked for the OP.

Use the following code to simplify your equation to the required step:

```
syms x
yp_tb = exp(x)*(tan(x)-x)/2; 
yp_mt = (x*exp(x)*tan(x)^2)/2 - (exp(x)*(2*x - sin(2*x)))/(4*cos(x)^2);
simplify(yp_mt, 3)
```

Also look at the documentation for [simplify](http://in.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html)